# Is it possible to display a Report Document that constitutes a SAP Crystal Report within a Print Dialog as a Print Document content

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, system.printing

Print Documents only take in String values. Is it possible to display a Report Document of .rpt within the same, So as to facilitate Print Preview in Windows C#.NET?

Have created a Report Document and this document shows a Crystal Report

```
   ReportDocument doc=new ReportDocument;

  doc=ReportDataSource(ReportLocConnect);
```

here `doc` contains a crystal report need to show the same as Print Document in Print Preview Dialog

Please help on Displaying report document as a Print Document!

Comment: What does ReportDataSource(ReportLocConnect) do? also you can simplifies this code by writing var doc = ReportDataSource(ReportLocConnect);. there is no need to instantiate doc if you are going to overwrite it anyway.

Comment: Are you able to provide a complete example? Also, have you looked at SAP CrystalReportsViewer?

Comment: @Patel:ReportDataSource is the source of where the Report is obtained.

Comment: @Jamleck:Will provide a complete example.Actually i need to display a SAP Crystal Report in the Print Preview as the Print Document! This is why i dont need a CrystalReportViewer!